# Wordpress: attempting to update plugins results in 503 error after several minutes

Tags: wordpress, apache

I'm using wp 3.4.2 on a hosting service. I can access the ftp server and make changes using a ftp client (ie I have the correct credentials). I inherited the website and I'm trying to update everything, but as a precaution I started with the plugins.

**The problem**

When I try to update a plugin using the admin dashboard, after clicking "update now", the page keeps loading for several (about/at least 5) minutes. Afterwards I get a *Error 503 Service Unavailable* error. FTP settings are hardcoded in wp-config.php. This happens with all the plugins.

**I solved it already, answer below.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone happens to stumble upon this problem, in `wp-config.php` the ftp host should be set to `localhost` instead of `ftp://yourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution i have found on my webhost was that the database user the wordpress installation used lacked the permission to refrence and to delete. Solved by giving the DB user FULL access.